# How to serve a static JSON file from Phoenix with charset utf-8 for Filestack

Tags: json, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app and on the javascript side I use the Filestack client. Filestack requests a JSON file from my server. I had put the file in my asset directory and it gets loaded but the Filestack Javascript client crashes with an error because it can't read the json do to german umlauts (öäü). I looked at the header and it gets served like this `Content-type: application/json`. I think what I need is `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. I also use webpack2 btw.
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plug.Static` uses the `mime` package to set the `content-type` header. You can override the value for `json` as described in the [`mime` package's README](https://github.com/elixir-lang/mime#usage). Make sure your app is using `mime` version 1.1.0 or later because the builtin mime types were not overridable due to a [bug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/mime/issues/14) that was fixed in 1.1.0.

Add this to `config/config.exs`:

```
config :mime, :types, %{"application/json; charset=utf-8" => ["json"]}
```

Then, force recompile `mime`:

```
mix deps.clean --build mime
```

and then start Phoenix:

```
mix phoenix.server
```

After this, the `content-type` of `.json` files served by `Plug.Static` should be `application/json; charset=utf-8`:

```
$ curl -I localhost:4000/js/foo.json
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: Cowboy
date: Sat, 18 Feb 2017 14:36:51 GMT
content-length: 3
cache-control: public
etag: 8EA91E
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! Thank you very much!